# Kentico based content in pardot

Tags: kentico

I have some CTAs based on a custom page type. I'm wondering if there is a way to get a json object so i can consume that in some JS on a pardot landing page i'm building out?

I'd like to avoid cutting and pasting the rendered HTML as I know these will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of our REST services?

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/getting-data-using-rest/examples-of-data-retrieved-via-the-rest-service#ExamplesofdataretrievedviatheRESTservice-JSON

On the other hand, if REST is overkill for you you can take advantage of the Custom Response web part and return just the JSON you need or possibly this custom web part:

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/custom-response-repeater

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!